# Woocommerce - Show/hide checkbox at the checkout page based on the order total value and if another checkbox is checked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a PHP function (which contains jQuery) at the checkout page that hides one checkbox if another is not checked (all works fine).

```
/***START - SHOW HIDE DEPOSIT CHECKBOX***/

function action_wp_footerr() {
    // Only on checkout
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // Selector
        var my_input = $(".forwarding");
        var my_depo = '#my_id_field';
        
        // Show or hide
        function show_or_hide() {
            if ( $( my_input ).is(':checked') ) {
                return $( my_depo ).show();
            } else {
                $( my_depo ).hide();
                $( "#my_id" ).prop( "checked", false );
            }           
        }
        
        // Default
        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
            show_or_hide();
        });
        
        // On change
        $( 'form.checkout' ).change(function() {
            show_or_hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footerr', 10, 0 );

/***END - SHOW HIDE DEPOSIT CHECKBOX***/
```

Current if statement is as follows:

```
if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
```

I need to add a **condition** to this if statement where the total order value needs to be greater than 1800.

To get the order total I use:

```
$total = $order->get_total();
```

Further, I add another variable that contains the value of 1800

```
$value = 1800;
```

Now I try to add this condition to the current if statement

```
if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && $total > $value ) :
```

However, now the function does not work and the frontend gets distorted.

How to add this **condition** properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**START - SHOW HIDE DEPOSIT CHECKBOX**/

function action_wp_footerr() {
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    $total = $cart->total;
    
    // Only on checkout
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url()) :
    
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        // Selector
        var my_input = $(".forwarding");
        var my_depo = '#my_id_field';
        var cart_value = <?php echo $total; ?>;
        
        // Show or hide
        function show_or_hide() {
            if ( $( my_input ).is(':checked') && cart_value > 1800) {
                console.log('value > 1800');
                return $( my_depo ).show();
            } else {
                console.log('value < 1800');
                $( my_depo ).hide();
                $( "#my_id" ).prop( "checked", false );
            }           
        }
        
        // Default
        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
            show_or_hide();
        });
        
        // On change
        $( 'form.checkout' ).change(function() {
            show_or_hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'action_wp_footerr', 10, 0 );

/**END - SHOW HIDE DEPOSIT CHECKBOX**/
```